# Camunda/Activiti process loops endessly in JavaDelegate's

Tags: infinite-loop, activiti, camunda

I have problem with camunda process that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc7VX.png).
This process loops endlessly in an non deterministic way in steps SetId and CreateObjectsForId (both are JavaDelegates).

I am using camunda 7.5.

I have some BaseJavaDelegate implemented like:

```
@Override
public void execute( DelegateExecution aExecution ) throws Exception
{
    logBefore( aExecution );
    try
    {
        executeInTry( aExecution );
    }
    catch( Throwable aEx )
    {
        aEx.printStackTrace();
        throw new BpmnError( "GENERIC_ERROR_CODE", aEx.getMessage() );
    }
   logAfter( aExecution );
}
```

Log from example execution:

```
01.06.2017 15:32:53,902;pool-6-thread-2:...wf.base.BaseJavaDelegate;callExecuteInTry;DEBUG;
Starting task:
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: SetId
    TransactionId: null 
...
01.06.2017 15:32:54,664;pool-6-thread-2:...wf.base.BaseJavaDelegate;callExecuteInTry;DEBUG;
Ended task: 
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: SetId
    TransactionId: null
...
Starting task:
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: d161958b-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: CreateObjectsForId
    TransactionId: null
...
01.06.2017 15:37:53,886;pool-6-thread-3:...wf.base.BaseJavaDelegate;callExecuteInTry;DEBUG;
Starting task:
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: SetId
    TransactionId: null 
...
01.06.2017 15:37:53,893;pool-6-thread-3:...wf.base.BaseJavaDelegate;callExecuteInTry;DEBUG;
Ended task: 
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: SetId
    TransactionId: null 
...
Starting task:
    ProcessDefinitionId: ...Process1:1:1
    ProcessInstanceId: ae2ecf43-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ExecutionId: d161958b-46ce-11e7-8483-005056b37c6b
    ActivityId: CreateObjectsForId
    TransactionId: null
```

From log you can see that SetId was started second time while CreateObjectsForId never finished.
No exception is thrown during this execution.
Also previous steps are all executed in the same thread but when the loop begins process starts using another thread/two threads.

I have tried to bypass this problem by designing process like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dIZa.png).
This time implementation of SetId step knows that it was entered for the second time and with exclusive gate process should go further.

Unfortunately the process still loops! No exception from my code. No OptimisticLockException. No any other exception from camunda.
I have no clue what else can cause process to loop like this.

Comment: Please add the Camunda version and the entire BPMN XML of your process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you have recursive code here.
Your delegate executes, and then you take the execution and execute it again in executeInTry()....rinse and repeat.

Am I missing something?
Greg

Comment: This BaseJavaDelegate is an abstract class. The only thing is does is just wrapping execution of implementors with try/catch in order to catch everything (and rethrow it as BPMError). My SetId and CreateObjectsForId are implementing BaseJavaDelegate. Camunda calls execute method and this method calls executeInTry - the real implementation of my JavaDelegates.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my problem.
I have been running embedded camunda engine.

Once, I decided to try running the same code on application server (wildfly in my case). Now I got clear messages in log that my transactions we just taking too long. [Here](https://forum.camunda.org/t/jobs-are-not-being-executed-or-with-heavy-delay/469) you can find solution of this problem (transactions timeout and jobs-executor lockTimeInMillis)